# SQL Server 2012 Connection String

Tags: sql-server, connection-string

I have just installed 2012 SQL Server. All went well..

SQL Server 2012 is installed as the default instance as the client was running on an SQL Express 2008 edition.

Enabled using SQL Config manager Named Pipes Protocol as it defaults to Dis-abled.

Remote Connections is checked on in SQL Server by default and double checked it was on.

Stopped and Started the service

Then tried to launch the client application which worked fine on 2008 R2, but it keeps failing to connect.. I have tried an array of things in the conection string including the usual (local), localhost, the IP Address... etc.

I keep getting the same standard error: Database Error 2 ensure remote connections is enabled and the instance name is correct blah: Named Pipes provider error 40.

here is the connection string that is being used;

```
connectionString="Data Source=(local);InitialCatalog=AssetManager;
Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=blah" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
```

Is there something different in 2012 that needs to added to the connection string ? what am i missing, have checked on-line, nothing obvious to find...

Comment: Is the browser service running? I don't know if that is on by default in a 2012 install. Although just noticed you mentioned trying by IP address and that failed as well, so that probably isn't it. Did you install it with a different instance name (like (localhost)\SQL2012Express) or something like that?

Comment: Are the client and server on the same machine? If they are different then (local) is incorrect. Normally I would use TCP rather than named pipes but it's just a different port number on the end. This link has some good network level troubleshooting that you can follow: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sql_protocols/2008/04/30/steps-to-troubleshoot-sql-connectivity-issues/

Comment: This question will require feedback from the original user to solve... they have not been seen for six years. Not sure why this was bumped

Answer (score 0):

These may be the following reasons that cause the Named Pipes Provider Error 40

1 Incorrect connection string, such as using SqlExpress.

2 NP was not enabled on the SQL instance.

3 Remote connection was not enabled.

4 Server not started, or point to not a real server in your connection string.

5 Other reasons such as incorrect security context.

For more information, go to following link:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sql_protocols/archive/2007/03/31/named-pipes-provider-error-40-could-not-open-a-connection-to-sql-server.aspx?PageIndex=2

It may help you.